# Написание СЕО-текстов

Tags: сео

Прошу, поделитесь опытом (лучше личными, а не ссылками на статьи, которые каждый может найти и сам)! Когда пишешь СЕО-текст, оказываешься перед дилеммой: с одной стороны нужна уникальность, а с другой - ключевые слова. При этом часто сталкиваешься с ситуацией, когда в тексте должны упоминаться длинные названия учреждений или чего-то еще, изменять которые нельзя и на которые, разумеется, ругается Адвего (программа для определения уникальности), потому что эти названия встречаются в интернете сплошь и рядом. Что же делать? Помогите, пожалуйста, решить эту проблему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С "Адвего" работать не приходилось, так как в вузах в лучшем случае "антиплагиатом" пользуются, вот несколько способов повысить оригинальность текста при использовании заимствований, найденных мной при написании дипломных работ, но повода их применить на практике еще не представилось:

1. Заменить текст картинкой. Со скрина текста вырезается нужная часть и вставляется как картинка, важно следить за соблюдением масштаба.
2. Раньше проходила замена русских букв на идентичные на вид латинские, но это уже не работает, правда думаю можно попробовать с греческим алфавитом (гипотеза).